# p4python windows x64 build link errors

Tags: python, windows, build, 64-bit, p4python

I've been trying to build p4python on 64 bit for windows, but I am getting the following link errors:

```
Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\P4API.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\P4API.exp

librpc.lib(netssltransport.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSLeay referenced in function "private: void __cdecl NetSslTransport::ValidateRuntimeVsCompiletimeSSLVersion(class Error *)" (?ValidateRuntimeVsCompiletimeSSLVersion@NetSslTransport@@AEAAXP
EAVError@@@Z)
librpc.lib(netssltransport.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol CRYPTO_num_locks referenced in function InitLockCallbacks
librpc.lib(netssltransport.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol CRYPTO_set_locking_callback referenced in function InitLockCallbacks
librpc.lib(netssltransport.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol CRYPTO_set_id_callback referenced in function InitLockCallbacks
librpc.lib(netssltransport.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol CRYPTO_set_dynlock_create_callback referenced in function InitLockCallbacks
librpc.lib(netssltransport.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol CRYPTO_set_dynlock_lock_callback referenced in function InitLockCallbacks
librpc.lib(netssltransport.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol CRYPTO_set_dynlock_destroy_callback referenced in function InitLockCallbacks
librpc.lib(netssltransport.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSL_load_error_strings referenced in function "private: void __cdecl NetSslTransport::SslClientInit(class Error *)" (?SslClientInit@NetSslTransport@@AEAAXPEAVError@@@Z)
librpc.lib(netssltransport.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSLv23_method referenced in function "private: struct ssl_ctx_st * __cdecl NetSslTransport::CreateAndInitializeSslContext(char const *)" (?CreateAndInitializeSslContext@NetSslTransport@@AEA
    APEAUssl_ctx_st@@PEBD@Z)
librpc.lib(netssltransport.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSL_library_init referenced in function "private: void __cdecl NetSslTransport::SslClientInit(class Error *)" (?SslClientInit@NetSslTransport@@AEAAXPEAVError@@@Z)

build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\P4API.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

I am building using 64 bit openssl dynamic libraries built for vs 2015 (this includes libcrypto.lib and libssl.lib), and I am using p4api dynamic libraries for vs 2015 (fetched from p4 website).

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because I was pointing to the wrong p4api library.